# WebAPI - Attribute Routing POST not working with WebAPI Cors?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have the following controller which should accept username and password as payload in a POST. If I change it to HttpGet it works.

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost("login/{username}/{password}")]
    [AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    public Login Login(string username, string password)
    {
        Login login = new Login();
        if (username == "user" && password == "pw") login.Success = true;
        else login.Success = false;
        return login;
    }
}
```

The OPTIONS request can pass through but POST fails.

[image]

OPTIONS header:

[image]

OPTIONS response:

[image]

POST header:

[image]

POST response:

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have defined your route with `[HttpPost("login/{username}/{password}")]` but you don't send the usename and password in the url but in the request body so your route doesn't match so you get the 404.

So you need to change your route  to `[HttpPost("login")]`

In itself it won't work because with Web.API you cannot have multiple action arguments coming from the request body so you need a complex type:

```
public class LoginInfo {
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

So for fixed action should look like this:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public Login Login(LoginInfo loginInfo)
{
    Login login = new Login();

    if (loginInfo.username == "user" && loginInfo.password == "pw") {
        login.Success = true;
    } else {
        login.Success = false;
    }

    return login;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this right away. But as you see here in scenario 5 [HttpPost("my/action1/{param1}/{param2")] should work: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Attribute%20routing%20in%20Web%20API

Comment: Yes that should work because in that case both param1 and param2 are comming from the URL and NOT the requst body as in your case.

Comment: Why would you use HttpPost then? Makes no sense to mee.

Comment: Because the action still can do some state changing thing so semantically it makes sense to have the verb as POST. But the action requires no more parameters beside what is given in the URL.

Comment: BTW it is possible to pass a single parameter to a POST method without creating a complex type. You just need to add a [FromBody] attribute to this parameter.And as stated here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api this won't work with two parameters.