# AddWithValue method on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using AddStringWithValue method in ASP.NET using C#

My HTML code is

```
<form class="login-modal-content animate" action="">   
    <asp:Login ID = "Login" runat = "server" OnAuthenticate="ValidateUser"></asp:Login>        
    <div class="input">
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="email" style="margin:8px 2px 5px 2px;" placeholder="Email"/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="password" id="password" style="margin:5px 2px 8px 2px;" placeholder="**********"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
    <f style="padding-left: 4px">Not yet registered? <f style="color:rgb(176,224,230); cursor:pointer" onclick="document.getElementById('Sign_Up_Form').style.display='block';document.getElementById('Login_Form').style.display='none';">Sign Up</f></f>
</form>
```

My C# code for the method is:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Login.email);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Login.password);
```

The problem is, it is giving red underline under  email and password. Shouldn't we  identify them with Id? Please tell me how to identify them..

I am sorry, I still don't know how to format my codes here..

edit:

The error message is

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' does not 
>   contain a definition for 'email' and no extension method 'email' accepting a 
>   first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The HTML is in masterpage.master and c# code is in masterpage.master.cs

Comment: It's not clear where that method is declared, or whether there's a `Login` property for it to use. If it's in the code-behind for the form, you can probably just use `email` and `password` rather than `Login.email` and `Login.password`... but it's pretty unclear at the moment. It would help if you'd give the full error message as well, rather than just "giving red underline".

Comment: Some SQL parameter code has nothing to do with ASPX code.  You need to include a [MCVE] with your question

Comment: The error message is:
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' does not contain a definition for 'email' and no extension method 'email' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Related: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that you want to send the client side input value to your sql statement, or something like that ?
You have to perform a post request to get the value into your c# backend.
Try something like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389149/how-to-access-html-form-input-from-asp-net-code-behind).

Another possible way (i would prefer) instead of this one is to create a JSON oject that you can easily post and access via c# [HttpPost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638199/web-api-routing-and-http-post).
I recommend to use the ApiController for this purpose.

Good luck ;)

Comment: should I write anything in the action attribute?

Comment: You only have to place the  [HttpPost] Attribute above the Method , and you are able to set a custom Route URL with [Route(controllername\methodname)]. After that you are able to create a JS file where you can place the Route URLs inside and then accessing it via for example: myvariablename: "mycontrollerurl" ; Save your URLs inside a JS file to access it from everywhere inside your web APP frontend