# Can't hit HttpPost Web Api from Swift

Tags: .net, swift, asp.net-web-api

I have a HttpPOST .Net WebApi with a route: `http://blah/api/CarValues?userId=1&carId=5&value=12.12`. 
This webApi is published on Azure, and I can call it via Postman. However, inside of my swift app, when I try to post data to this endpoint, I get this:

`responseString = Optional("{\"Message\":\"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI \'http://blah.net/api/CarValues\'.\"}")`

Here is my current code:

```
func postCarInfo() {
        // Posts to cloud

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: webApiUrl)!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "userId=1&carId=5&value=200.00"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        }
        task.resume()


    }
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I have tried hitting this endpoint several times successfully via postman, and I can access the other get methods in the webApi, just not the Post one. I also set `NSAppTransportSecurity` to allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`, but I still can't access the endpoint.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is related:

[WebAPI - Attribute Routing POST not working with WebAPI Cors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18036960/6541007)

If you included the params into the route, the params need to exist in the URL, not in the body of the request.

Try this:

```
let paramString = "userId=1&carId=5&value=200.00"
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: webApiUrl+"?"+paramString)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let task = ...
```