# Getting HTTP 404 error in a POST request - C#

Tags: c#, .net, post, asp.net-core

I am trying to create new customerId and orderId.
Which then will display a new order and retrieve code 201 for created.
I can't see why the code is not working. Is there something I'm missing?

Been working on this for several days with no luck.
Hopefully you can see where I have gone wrong.

Still new to programming and really appreciate your help.

Code is below:

***Models:***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Project.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
       public string CustomerId { get; set; }
       public string FirstName { get; set; }
       public string LastName { get; set; }
       public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    }

   public class Order
   {
       public string OrderId { get; set; }
       public string Product { get; set; }
       public string Status { get; set; }
       public double Price { get; set; }
   }

    public class CustomerOrder
    {
      public string CustomerId {get; set;}
      public string OrderId { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

---

***Repositories:***

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Project.Models;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Text;


namespace Project.Repositories
{
   public class OrderRepository
   {

       private static List<Order> _Orders;
       private static List<CustomerOrder> _CustomerOrder;

       static OrderRepository()
       {
           _Orders = new List<Order>();
           _CustomerOrder= new List<CustomerOrder>();

           _Orders.Add(new Order
           {
               OrderId = "124",
               Product= "Shirts",
               Status= "On it's way",
               Price= 100.20,
           });

           _Orders.Add(new Order
           {
               OrderId= "122",
               Product= "Pants",
               Status= "Not ready",
               Price= 300.30,
           });

           _Orders.Add(new Order
           {
               OrderId= "143",
               Product= "Deadpool",
               Status= "On it's way",
               Price= 6.20,
           });

           _Orders.Add(new Order
           {
               OrderId= "156",
               Product= "Socks",
               Status= "Not ready",
               Price= 3.30,
           });

           _CustomerOrder.Add(new CustomerOrder
           {
               CustomerId = "578",
               OrderId = "156",
           });
}

public static void SaveNewCustomerOrder(string customerId, string orderId, CustomerOrder customerOrder)
{
    order.CustomerID = customerId;
    order.OrderId= orderId;
    Order.Add(order);
}
```

---

***Controllers:***

OrderController.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Project.Models;
using Project.Repositories;

namespace Project.Controllers
{
   public class OrderController : Controller
   {
      [HttpPost("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview")]
       public IActionResult Post([FromRoute] string customerId, string orderId, [FromBody] CustomerOrder customerOrder)
       {
          OrderRepository.SaveNewCustomerOrder(customerId, orderId, customerOrder);

          return Ok();
       }
    }
 }
```

---

Comment: What's your request body and url?

Comment: @D-Shih URL : `http://localhost:5000/customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview` and the request body should be `customerId and orderId`. If that's what you are asking for?

Comment: You could create an no parameters GET action, to check whether the endpoint is responding at all. Maybe it's something with your setup?

Comment: What does *not working mean*? You show code say it is not working. What what the expected behavior and what actually happens? Only then would we be able to provide some help other than guess what is happening from *not working*. Update the question with the relevant details.

Comment: @Nkosi I wish to display a new order and retrieve code 201 for created.

Comment: And what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview")]
public IActionResult Post([FromRoute] string customerId, [FromRoute] string orderId, [FromBody] CustomerOrder customerOrder)
{
    OrderRepository.SaveNewCustomerOrder(customerId, orderId, customerOrder);

    return Ok();
}
```

I don't think is the answare that you looking for, but start to add orderID like a [fromRoute] parameter, when you do the debug, do you see the right values in the parameters? Are you using aspnet .core 2.0?

are you sure the path is correct? I read in the previus comment this one : 
http://localhost:5000/customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview

check is this path:
http://localhost:5000/api/customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview

Comment: Please use the answer section to only provide solutions, you can ask for information in comments under the question, if you cannot comment you are expected to wait for OP to clarify himself.

Comment: Debug in visual studio code is not working as expecting as it does not hit any marker i have assigned. I am using .core 2.0, yes.

Comment: So you are receiving Error 404 because you got a problem with URL, I am pretty sure that is your URL not found

Answer (score 0):

You should update your HttpPost("Path")

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18036960/webapi-attribute-routing-post-not-working-with-webapi-cors) And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638199/web-api-routing-and-http-post)

it it better to use

`[RoutePrefix("Path")]` with class/controller  and

`[Route("Path")]` Action Method decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated your code but there is some issues with what you are expecting.

1)

```
public static void SaveNewCustomerOrder(string customerId, string orderId, CustomerOrder customerOrder)
{
    order.CustomerID = customerId;
    order.OrderId= orderId;
    Order.Add(order);
}
```

Inside that method you are trying to add customerId and orderId but they do not belong to the order class. You then try to add this order to the list of orders.
I think you might have meant to pass in the order instead of the customer order. I have the following class and controllers working:

Controller:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ben22.Repositories;
using ben22.Models.Models;

namespace ben22.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview")]
        public IActionResult Post([FromRoute] string customerId, string orderId, [FromBody] Order order)
        {
            OrderRepository.SaveNewCustomerOrder(customerId, orderId, new Order());

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated SaveNewCustomerOrder:

```
public static void SaveNewCustomerOrder(string customerId, string orderId, Order order)
{
    var newCustomer = new CustomerOrder
    {
        CustomerId = customerId,
        OrderId = orderId
    };
    _CustomerOrder.Add(newCustomer);

    _Orders.Add(order);

}
```

Hitting the following endpoint (Replace yourPort):

http://localhost:{yourPort}/customers/1/orders/2/overview

Body:

```
{
  "orderId": "55",
  "product": "Football",
  "status": "Approved",
  "price": 9.99
}
```

In addition if this is not working, I would check the your launchUrl in visual studio and possibly restart it.

Comment: I'm using visual studio code, any ideas for restarting launchUrl? =p but I will try your solution and see how it goes.

Comment: Just for reference I has using postman to but the endpoint. If you are using postman please ensure you select post from the type of request.

Comment: I've tried postman and it's weird. It passes customerId and orderId just fine, but i'm getting `null` in order `_Orders.Add(order);` So it won't create a new order.

Comment: how are you sending the request? and could you post your updated saveNewCustomerOrder method?

Comment: If using Postman, please ensure you have set the request to POST. In Body, select raw and add the Body code as I have previously provided.

Comment: I did exactly as you did. Btw, i did get 200 response which i did not expect as i was expecting 201.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174672/discussion-between-benl2-and-niknak).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following

> I wish to display a new order and retrieve code 201 for created

The following is meant only as a demonstrated example of the request above and is not directly taken from your example.

```
public class OrderController : Controller {
    //...removed for brevity

    //POST "customers/578/orders/1576/overview
    [HttpPost("customers/{customerId}/orders/{orderId}/overview")]
    public IActionResult Post(string customerId, string orderId) {
        var order = orderRepository.CreateNewCustomerOrder(customerId, orderId);
        if(order == null) {
            return BadRequest();
        }
        //return 201 created status code along with 
        //the route name, route value, and the actual object that is created
        return CreatedAtRoute("GetOrder", new { orderId = order.OrderId }, order);
    }

    //GET orders/157
    [HttpGet("orders/{orderId}", Name = "GetOrder")]
    public IActionResult GetOrder(string orderId) {
        var order = orderRepository.GetOrder(orderId);
        if(order == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(order);
    }
}
```